# DateTime format in ASP.NET Web API when passing complex object as a Query string

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I have this method in MyController derived from ApiController:

```
public async Task MyAction([FromUri] MyDto input)
```

MyDto class:

```
public class MyDto 
{
    public string MyProp { get; set; }
    public DateTime MyDate { get; set; }
}
```

The request URI is http://server/api/myaction?myprop=value&mydate=22/04/2015

So I want to set the parsing format for DateTime for Action or for Controller.

Something like this:

```
public class MyDto 
{
    public string MyProp { get; set; }
    [DateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")]
    public DateTime MyDate { get; set; }
}
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks for help!

Comment: You will be far better of passing it in ISO format - `....&mydate=2015-04-22`. Either that or set the culture of the server to one that accepts dates in `dd/MM/yyyy` format (in the `web.config.cs` file)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Unfortunately I can't change this format :( The another system is using this format already

Comment: If that's the case, set the server culture, and if you do not want to do that because other types may use a different culture, then you will need to create a custom ModelBinder

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks

Comment: @StephenMuecke That doesn't work in Owin Self Host. I've tried to use 
Owin Globalization Module. So I guess I need to change DateTime to string and parse manually or create ModelBinder.